# Why is this Twig code generating large numbers of DB queries?

Tags: templating, database

I have a Twig include that generates a News Archive side-bar. It works great, but I've just noticed that on a particular project it's contributing in the region of 800 DB Queries when caching is off.

What have I missed about the mechanics of the group filter? Because I can see no other reason why this should generate more than one query?

```
{% cache globally %}
    {% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('newsItems').limit(null).all() %}
    <div class="archives widget">
        <h2>News Archive</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for year, entriesInYear in allEntries | group("postDate | date('Y')") %}
                <li>
                    <a href="/news/archive/{{ year }}">{{ year }}</a>
                    <ul>
                        {% for month, entriesInMonth in entriesInYear | group("postDate|date('m')") | reverse(true) %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="/news/archive/{{ year }}/{{ month }}">
                                    {{ entriesInMonth[0].postDate|date('F') }}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div><!-- .archives -->
{% endcache %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is below. 
**EDIT: only for MySQL 5.7.4 and lower! Higher versions break.**

For whatever reason, the mechanics of the `group` filter in this case was producing a new query for every Entry. Below, resolves this by doing the same job in a more performant way. I'm not entirely sure of the mechanics of how this works, but the answer was supplied over on the Discord support channel and I thought it worth cross-posting to here. Thanks Sebastian Lenz!

```
{% cache globally %}
    {% set postDates = craft.entries({
        section: 'newsItems',
        select: 'postDate',
        limit: null,
        groupBy: ['DATE_FORMAT(postDate, "%Y-%m")'],
    }).column() %}

    <div class="archives widget">
        <h2>News Archive</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for year, postDatesInYear in postDates|group("object|date('Y')") %}
                <li>
                    <a href="/news/archive/{{ year }}">{{ year }}</a>
                    <ul>
                        {% for month, postDatesInMonth in postDatesInYear|group("object|date('m')")|reverse(true) %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="/news/archive/{{ year }}/{{ month }}">
                                    {{ postDatesInMonth[0]|date('F') }}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div><!-- .archives -->
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: NOTE: This appears to only work with MySQL versions below 5.7.5.